# Unable to use "cm unlock" command

Tags: plasticscm

We are using Plastic SCM cloud server, and I am unable to use the `cm unlock [server] [guid]` command to unlock locked files. It returns the error:

`Only administrators can execute 'cm unlock' command. You're not an administrator so you can't run 'cm unlock' command.`

However the user which I am using is listed as an Admin on the Plastic Cloud Organization page and is in the Administrators group, yet I still get this message.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this by going accessing the `Server repository permissions` on the repository, and setting the owner to the Administrators group.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you. I searched their documentation and also the `cm` command help, but I found nothing about that.